# intellij - setting to replace the caret at the beginning of each line with correct indent

Tags: intellij-idea

I am looking for the setting that forces the caret to placed at the beginning of each line. Currently if I click anywhere, the caret gets positioned there. It is not the behavior I like, I would like it to be replaced, in order to prevent me to do it incorrectly. I think it is an option commonly used, and was standard in the intellij I became in some other company but I am bad at describing it. 
Sorry for my approximative vocabulary and thanks for any hint.

Comment: you can move it to the start of the line by pressing the home key https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/basic-editing.html and can enable or disable placing carets at the end of each line. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/general.html#after_end

Comment: home key works, but how can I make it automatic ? I want to make sure that the caret is never misplaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to **File → Settings**
2. On the left pane, expand **Editor**, then select **General**.
3. Find the **Virtual Space** section, and uncheck "Allow placement of caret after end of line".